# Angular Observables Unsubscribe async pipe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

> I'm building an App using Angular + Ionic.

When I present the data in an **observable** in my template using the **async pipe**.

My understanding is that **Angular** automatically **unsubscribe** from the observable when the component is **destroyed**, but, if I move to another page, the **ngOnDestroy** event is not being fired. Does it mean that I'm not **unsubscribing** from the **observable**?

Thanks!

Comment: Async pipe with ng-container  automatically unsubscribes from the declared observable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`unsubscribe` and `ngOnDestroy` are 2 different concepts :

- `unsubscribe` closes an observer stream : the subscription won't listen to new events
- `ngOnDestroy` is ran when a directive is destroyed (removed from the DOM)

`async` pipes are automatically unsubscribing from the observables they're fed with : but that isn't because of the `ngOnDestroy` function.

If your function doesn't get triggered, it either means that you don't destroy your component, or that you have an issue.

If so, please provide a sandbox reproducing it, for instance on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ionic stacks views so the best method is to manually destroy subscriptions in the ionViewDidLeave lifecycle hook.